# how to change a global variable in Pascal?

Tags: arrays, pascal, procedure

So I've got this simple program in Pascal, it starts with:

```
type
   arrayy=array[1..10] of integer;
var
   arr:arrayy;
```

Then I wrote a short procedure (let's call it proc) with arr as an argument. Inside the procedure, arr is changed.

Then, in the main part of the code I've got something like this:

-print arr

-proc(arr)

-print arr

The array doesn't change at all, altough it should. In my previous program when I had this problem, I would just put the command to print the array inside the procedure, but now I can't do that.
I tried doing this:

```
procedure proc(var arr)
```

but then the array is completely different than it should be, as if it was a new one.

Can anybody help me please? What can I do to print the changed array in the main part of the code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the *relevant portions* of your code here. We can't explain what might be wrong (or how to fix it) if we can't see what you're doing in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
program ChangeArrayExample;

{ Free Pascal Compiler }

type
    IntArray = array[1..5] of integer;

var
    MyIntArray : IntArray;
    I : integer;

procedure MyProc(var MyIntArray : IntArray);
begin
    for I := Low(MyIntArray) to High(MyIntArray) do
        MyIntArray[I] := 2 * I;
end;

begin
    for I := Low(MyIntArray) to High(MyIntArray) do
    begin
        MyIntArray[I] := I;
        Writeln(MyIntArray[I]);
    end;

    MyProc(MyIntArray);
    Writeln();

    for I := Low(MyIntArray) to High(MyIntArray) do
        Writeln(MyIntArray[I]);
end.
```

array before: 1 2 3 4 5

array after:  2 4 6 8 10

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, so please post your full code.